# Lock process until subprocess reaches a certain point

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am running multiple subprocesses in parallel, but I need to lock each process until the subprocess gives an output (via print function). The subprocesses are running a python script that has been packaged to an executable.

The code looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess
import os


def main(args):

    l,inpath = args
    l.acquire()
    print "Running KNN.exe for files in %s" %   os.path.normpath(inpath).split('\\')[-1] 

    #Run KNN executable as a subprocess
    subprocess.call(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "KNN.exe"))
    #This is where I want to wait for any output from the subprocess before releasing the lock
    l.release()

    #Here I would like to wait until subprocess is done then print that it is done
    l.acquire()
    print "Done %s" % os.path.normpath(inpath).split('\\')[-1]
    l.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Set working directory path containing input text file
    os.chdir("C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\KNN")
    #Get folder names in directory containing GCM input
    manager = mp.Manager()
    l = manager.Lock()
    gcm_dir = "F:\FIDS_GCM_Data_CMIP5\UTRB\UTRB KNN-CAD\Input"
    paths = [(l, os.path.join(gcm_dir, folder)) for folder in os.listdir(gcm_dir)]    
    #Set up multiprocessing pool
    p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    #Map function through input paths
    p.map(main, paths)
```

So the goal is to lock the process so that a subprocess can be run until receiving an output. After which the lock can be released and the subprocess can continue, until it is complete, then I'd like to print that it is complete.

My question is how can I wait for the single (and only) output from the subprocess before releasing the lock on the process (out of multiple)?

Additionally how can I wait for the process to terminate then print that it is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes use of the `call` method, which already waits for the subprocess to finish (which means all output has already been generated).  I'm inferring from your question you'd like to be able to differentiate between when output is first written and when the subprocess is finished.  Below is your code with my recommended modifications inline:

```
def main(args):

    l,inpath = args
    l.acquire()
    print "Running KNN.exe for files in %s" %   os.path.normpath(inpath).split('\\')[-1]

    #Run KNN executable as a subprocess
    #Use the Popen constructor
    proc = subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "KNN.exe"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    #This is where I want to wait for any output from the subprocess before releasing the lock
    # Wait until the subprocess has written at least 1 byte to STDOUT (modify if you need different logic)
    proc.stdout.read(1)

    l.release()

    #Here I would like to wait until subprocess is done then print that it is done
    #proc.wait()
    (proc_output, proc_error) = proc.communicate()

    l.acquire()
    print "Done %s" % os.path.normpath(inpath).split('\\')[-1]
    l.release()
```

Note that the above doesn't assume you want to do anything with the subprocess's output other than check that it has been generated.  If you want to do anything with that output that is less trivial than the above (consume 1 byte then drop it on the floor), the `proc.stdout` (which is a `file` object) should represent everything that the subprocess generates while running.

Comment: Ah okay great! Yes, differentiating between the first output of the subprocess and its termination is exactly what I meant. In this case I only need the first output, but I think `proc.stdout` will be useful in the future.

Comment: @user2593236 I'm glad if it helped.  Just to re-emphasize the caveat in my answer, that first byte is being discarded if the result of `proc.stdout.read(1)` doesn't get assigned to anything.  So this is fine as long as "need the first output" means you don't mean "need to know what the first output byte was".  :)

Comment: @pbreach: the code as written in the answer may deadlock if the child process generates enough output (at least on Unix, I don't know whether pipe buffers can grow on Windows unlimited). You should read the output e.g., `deque(p.stdout, maxlen=0); p.stdout.close(); p.wait()` to discard it after your read the first byte or `out, err = p.communicate()` to capture the output in a string.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well-spotted...answer has been edited to consume the output with `communicate` instead of `wait` (I figure preserving the output provides more flexibility with what OP might want to do with the code later on).

Comment: @rchang: `proc_error` is always `None` unless `stderr=PIPE`